# Get index from array according to a value inside

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array with this structure:

```
[items] => Array
           (
              [0] => items Object
                     (
                      [id:protected] => waHf9YHIEcYZAu6NmwQ9rOUZ6amsYME3

                           )

                     [1] => items Object
                            (
                           [id:protected] => waHf9YHIEcYZAu6NmwQ9rOUZ6amsYME3
                            )

                )
```

Is there any way to get the index of the items according to the id:protected value? I want to unset this index based on the id value

I found a way bbut wanted to check if there is an option to not go trough all the array

```
foreach($items as $key => $val) {
            if($val->getId() == $idIwanttodeelte) {
                $index = $key;
            }
        }
//then unset according to index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove items from an array that you are currently traversing without any issue:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->getId() === $idToDelete) {
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could more easily use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php). This will create a new array without modifying the original

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($items, function($item) use ($idIwanttodeelte) {
    return $item->getId() != $idIwanttodeelte;
});
```